# Capture a video in raspberry pi camera model using C language

Tags: c, raspberry-pi3

I wrote a server code as the main server for all the clients. This program is multi-threaded and waits for the clients to connect. Once all the threads are created, they wait on thread accept. Once the connection is accepted, they wait on reception of file from clients. At the end of these threads reception, all the threads join so that system is at common point. This behavior repeats after every 40 seconds.

I need to capture video frames and transferring then integrated in the code?

Server.c

```
// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<pthread.h> //for threading , link with lpthread


#define LISTENING_PORT 8080
#define CLIENT_COUNT 4

void * handle_new_conn(void *server_fd)
{
    int valread;
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    int new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);

    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( LISTENING_PORT );

    /* Accept connection from client */
    if ((new_socket = accept(*((int *)server_fd),
                    (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                    (socklen_t*)&addrlen)) < 0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Code to handle new connection */
    valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    sleep(10);

    send(new_socket, hello , strlen(hello), 0);
    printf("Hello message sent\n");

    sleep(2);

    close(new_socket);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    char *hello = "Hello from server";
    pthread_t thread_id[4];
    int client_no = 0;
    int i;

    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                  &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( LISTENING_PORT );

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                 sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (listen(server_fd, CLIENT_COUNT - 1) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (1)
    {
        for (i=0; i < CLIENT_COUNT; i++)
        {
            /* Handle the accepted connection from client */
            if (pthread_create(&thread_id[client_no] , NULL,
                        handle_new_conn, (void*) &server_fd) < 0)
            {
                perror("Couldn't create thread");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            client_no++;
        }
        client_no = 0;
        for (i=0; i < CLIENT_COUNT; i++)
        {
            pthread_join(thread_id[client_no], NULL);
            printf("Thread [%d] destroyed\n",
                thread_id[client_no]);

            client_no++;
        }

        /* Wait for the next interval to fetch the feed */
        sleep(40);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SERVER_PORT 8080

void record_video()
{
    /* Record video that has to be transmitted */

}

void handle_request(int sock)
{
    char *hello = "Hello from client";
    char * buffer[1024] = {0};
    int valread;

    printf("Client sock id: %d\n", sock);

    sleep(2);

    /* Connection to the server will be handled here */
    send(sock , hello , strlen(hello) , 0 );
    printf("Hello message sent\n");
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n",buffer );

    close(sock);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sock = 0, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char *hello = "Hello from client";
    char buffer[1024] = {0};
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(&serv_addr, '0', sizeof(serv_addr));

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if(inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr)<=0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }

    record_video();

    handle_request(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It appears you have provided a good description of what code you have shown.  Then it appears you have made a (very poorly worded) request for someone to add a feature for you.  `void record_video(){ /* Record video that has to be transmitted */`.  What attempt have you made to fill that section, and what problems did you have with it?

Comment: this is the problem I want to capture a video using c which I cant unfortunately.

Comment: A request to _help with existing_ code is fine, but a request to _create_ code is generally way off-topic here.  Take your best shot at implementing the the thing you have described, then, if your implementation does not work, post your attempt, explaining what you have tried, how it failed and what expectations were not met.